# Assembly << operator

Tags: assembly, operating-system, operator-keyword

I am following some tutorials on operating system development and I found an article on the
multiboot header. These are some 'magic' values you have to define for it to work with 
GRUB2. These are the commands:

```
 # Declare constants used for creating a multiboot header.
 .set ALIGN,    1<<0             # align loaded modules on page boundaries
 .set MEMINFO,  1<<1             # provide memory map
 .set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  # this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
 .set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       # 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
 .set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) # checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot

 .section .multiboot
 .align 4
 .long MAGIC
 .long FLAGS
 .long CHECKSUM
```

Now what I don't understand, and i can't find anywhere, is what the 1<<0 and the 1<<1
do when we .set the align and meminfo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: these are macro assembler specific: they have the same meaning as the C equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely if you are interested in operating system development you have already encountered the `<<` operator in some other language? It's bitwise shift left. It is just used for defining some constants here, based on bit indices. Supposedly it is more clear than writing `.set ALIGN 1` and `.set MEMINFO 2`.

You should also learn to read the [manuals](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Infix-Ops.html), or else you won't have much luck with programming.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i read the gcc docs but i forgot the binutils ones. Yes i encoutered it in C and C++ but thought it would have a different function :)